# Recursively search subdirectories to find the first instance of file

Tags: r, file-io

I have a complex dataset that is spread over 80 directories for each city (C). Each of these cities have multiple and unidentical subdirectories of varying depth. To clarify this means that for an example: city 1 can have 5 subdirectories a-e, where each subdirectory again can have multiple subdirectories. Now I need to find the first instance of a .txt file in each terminal subdirectory and apply a function to the txt file (logical function that is already written). There are no .txt files in the pre-terminal subdirectories.

```
 lapply(list.dirs,function(x) {
if length(list.files(path=x,pattern=".txt"))==0 { 
**apply function to .txt file}**
else {**lapply list.dirs etc---**}
```

However, I´m left with a neverending loop this way. How can this be done efficiently?

Comment: what do you need to do once the first instance found ?

Comment: The `***` omitted code isn't very clear. Are you just recalling `list.dirs()` again with the same parameters? Have you set up a recursive function at all? Are you trying to do this in a single `lapply`?

Comment: That was my first thought, but I see that it cannot be done using lapply - hence the question.

Comment: also, you're applying function to txt file if there is none (might be a typo in your question ?)

Comment: There is always a .txt file in the terminal directory, but there can be many subdirectories before the .txt files are reached.

Comment: @Misha, I posted a basis for the function but, depending on what you want to do with the txt files, it may need to be modified, for exemple it may need to return some output

Comment: I might start with `mylist <- system("locate [fill in file name types,etc]")` and loop over the elements of the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may need something like this :

```
Treat_txt<-function(direct){
                if(length(list.files(direct,pattern=".txt"))){
                     do what you need to do with the text file
                } else {
                     dirs<-list.dirs(direct,full.names=T,recursive=F)
                     sapply(dirs,Treat_txt)
                }
           }
```

And then you can just call the function with the path of the "top" directory

Comment: It looked promising- but ended up with:Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

Comment: @Misha how many sub-sub-etc. so you have ? I never had this kind of error with a recursive function... Could you please tell what you're doing with the txt file ? it might help understanding the problem

Comment: Max 6 sub-dir. I modified the code somewhat after the error and it seems to be stuck in the same directory...Treat_txt<-function(direct){
  print(direct)
  if(length(list.files(direct,pattern=".txt"))){
  f<-dir()
  print(f)[1]
  } else {
    dirs<-list.dirs(direct,full.names=T)
    sapply(dirs,Treat_txt)
  }
}

Comment: maybe you can try just `if(length(...){print(list.files(direct,pattern=".txt"))} else{sapply(...)}` and let me know if you indeed get the listing of the txt file names

Comment: I have to abort after a while. Nothing happens.

Comment: @Misha, I made a small example and was able to reproduce the "evaluation nested too deply..." error. I fixed it with setting parameter `recursive=FALSE"` in `list.dirs` function (I edited my answer and modified my function). Now it works fine for me, I hope it will also work fine for your files. Sorry for the bug ! One last thing, for the function to work well, all folders must have either sub-folder(s) or txt file. If not, I will have to add a condition to tell the function to return nothing if one sub-sub-...-folder is "empty" (no sub-folder and no txt file).